# Is there a simpler calculation for the probability of exactly x occurrences over n trials?

Tags: probability, statistics

What I've worked out for this, where x is the specific number of occurrences, n is the number of trials and p is the probability of an occurrence during a single trial, is this:

\begin{equation}‎
\begin{cases}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{x}(
  (\begin{smallmatrix}
    (i+n-x-2)\\
    i
  \end{smallmatrix})*(1+x-i)+(1-p)^{n-x}*p^{x})& x<n-1\\\\
  (x+1)^{n-x}*(1-p)^{n-x}*p^{x}&x>n-2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}‎
I am trying to find a simpler version and a name I can use to reference this specific expression.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the binomial distribution?

Comment: What do $c$ and $t$ represent?

Comment: I wrote c and t instead of x and n by accident. I used those variables in my notebook.  I've fixed the equation so it now has x and n.

Comment: Yes, this is binomial distribution.  I just didn't know this kind of expression was called a binomial distribution because I found the expression without using any reference materials.  That answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplified equation that I didn't know the name of is
\begin{equation}
p_{x}=\binom{n}{x}*p^{x}*(1-s)^{n-x}
\end{equation}

Comment: Surely you meant to write $\binom nx p^x(1-p)^{n-x}.$

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that